# How do I enable jconsole on an opensuse machine?

Tags: firefox, opensuse

This may seem like a simple question, but I can't find a solid answer! How do I view jconsole in OpenSUSE 11.1? I have an applet that I'm hosting, and I'd like to be able to debug it on-the-server. However, I have no idea of how to pull up jconsole whilst in any browser on OpenSUSE.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch firefox from the terminal. Jconsole output is directed to firefox's standard out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute it directly with something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0.u1-sun-1.6.0.u1/bin/jconsole` ?

You will need java-1_6_0-sun-devel installed.

Comment: I'm looking to use the java console in the browser, which I can't do! Argh!